# TabWidget background image

Tags: android, tabwidget

I'm using a tabwidget in it app but I have a problem like this:

I added an image on each tab as follows code.

```
spec.setIndicator("", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_bg));
```

I want to appear on the tab just the image. But the image can not fill the tab. have a look around the border. How do I edit it and I want to display another image for the pressed state of the tab. How can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Check these: [Android - Change Tab bar background image](http://goo.gl/uN34c) and [Change Tab bar background color](http://goo.gl/EC6Mf)

Comment: Thank you for your links Paresh.

Comment: i am sure you are looking for these examples.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write `xml` file in `Drawable` directory to display another image for the pressed state of the tab like below

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed">
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/zen_button_red_focused">
    </item>

    <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/btn_search_dialog_voice_default">
    </item>

</selector>
```